# Access control allow origin CORS warning after adding integrity

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cors, google-cloud-storage, subresource-integrity

I have a JS file I have uploaded in a Google Cloud Project bucket. I am using this as a CDN. After I added an integrity check to my JS file that is being used as a CDN, I keep getting an error

`Access to script at someCDN.js from origin requestURL.com has been blocked by CORS policy.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'requestURL.com' is therefore not allowed access`

I was previously able to use this CDN without a problem before adding the integrity check. I double checked and made sure the requesting URLs are set as the permitted Origin Headers, but now I get this error after adding an integrity check.

The way I use the CDN is I build a `<script>` tag dynamically and append it to the DOM.

```
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  const parent = document.body

  script.src = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/some/file.js'
  script.integrity = 'sha384-someSRIhashkey'
  script.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')

  parent.appendChild(script)
```

The way I generated the HASH is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Tools_for_generating_SRI_hashes

After generating the hash with the command in the docs, I upload my file to the Google Cloud bucket as an object.

Comment: you can't use _integrity_ unless you can "ajax" in the script url, aka CORS enabled

Comment: @dandavis Hello, what do you mean by CORS enabled and unless I can AJAX in the script URL? I have set the requesting URLs for this CDN file as the permitted Origin Headers. Before I added the integrity, the requesting URLs were able to download the file from CDN without any problem

Comment: right, the integrity feature needs to be able to fetch the script as plain text in order to examine it and calc the hash, whereas normal scripts are allowed to come from anywhere, regardless of CORS support on the server.

Comment: @dandavis Okay, I am still having trouble on what you are talking about. So is this something I cannot do then? Or is it something that needs to be done on the Google Cloud Storage side?

Comment: i don't know that google cloud storage can even support CORS. it might, but it certainly wouldn't be on by default. It's a server-side problem for sure, whatever server that might be. readup on cors, it's well-covered.

Comment: @dandavis Hello, I did read on CORS and have been set on the requesting URLs in the list of allowed origins. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @dandavis It’d be great if you could post your response as answer, if you can make the time. Specifically I mean the point that using the `integrity` attribute requires the resource to be CORS-enabled. (I just now updated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity to also clarify the same point there.)

Comment: Hello @sideshowbarker, thanks for the input. Did you mean that I have to then add the domain from which my CDN is being hosted/served from into the list of allowed Origins Headers? So if my CDN is `https://storage.googleapis.com/some/file.js` I need to add `googleapis.com` as a permitted Origin Header / Request Header after adding an integrity check? Before the integrity check, everything worked fine. Also not sure if this has to be done on my server file or in the Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: It needs to be done on the `https://storage.googleapis.com` server for the `/some/file.js` path/resource. That resource must be served with an Access-Control-Allowed-Origin response header that either has the `*` wildcard as its value (to allow it to be accessed from all origins) or else has the requesting origin as its value.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I see. Then that would mean it has to be done in the Google Cloud Project and not my server file? Since I have defined a list of allowed origins that are permitted to access this resource and has worked up until the integrity check, I am assuming it is a Google Cloud Project configuartion

Comment: Yes, you need to check the response headers using browser devtools and ensure that the response has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header and that its value allows the origin of the document in which you’re embedding the resource. If the response doesn’t have that header or doesn’t have the necessary value, then I guess you need to show your Google Cloud config and ask for specific help with troubleshooting — and maybe you’d want to do that as a new separate question. (I don’t use Google Cloud, so I don’t think I can be much help to you in getting an answer about how to configure it)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors